# Why does this Java to generate a number multiplication table just repeat the same line?

Tags: java

Below is a Java class of which the output should have been

```
>1 2 3 4 5 6
>
>2 4 6 8 10 12
>
>...
>
>6 12 18 24 30 36
```

But it generates 6 lines of:

```
>2 4 6 8 10 12
```

Why does this happen?

```
public class alterable{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i=1;
        while(i<=6){    
            printMultiples(i);
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
    public static void printMultiples(int n){
        int i = 1;
        while(i<=6){
            System.out.print(2*i+" ");
            i=i+1;
            }
        System.out.println("");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost there, you forgot to user your `n` parameter:

```
public static void printMultiples(int n){
    int i = 1;
    while(i<=6){
        System.out.print(n*i+" ");
        i=i+1;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you use your parameter n inside of your printMultiples method? You don't. Solution: use `n` inside of this method.